# iPad only charges up to 1% and at that, only if charged from 0%

Tags: ipad, battery, charger

I plugged my iPad 3 in order to charge it. However, after a couple hours I noticed that it hadn't been charging.

It goes like this: First, it's completely off. Then, I plug it and charges up until it is on again with 1% battery and it won't charge any further than that. If I shut it off or the battery drains again, the same thing happens again.

Just one more thing, twice instead of the Apple logo, there was the iTunes icon. The iPad stayed like that but went back to normal after a reboot.

I have never had any problems with it, any ideas?

Comment: 1. Do you use the original cable and inverter?   
2. Are you charging from the wall, your car, a power bank or from a computer?   3. Do the charger work with other devices?

Comment: 1) both originals 2) wall,  now you mention my computer can't recognize the usb 3) it works with my phone

Comment: Have you tried with another cable?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like its about time to buy a new cable and possibly an ipad charger. I go through cables all the time on my iphone/ipad. They always get frayed where the cord meets the lightning plug. 
Go to best buy and buy a new one, worst comes to worst, you can always return it. If the new cable doesn't work, its time to call apple and send it in for service.

Comment: Good call - I often think a battery not charging is the fault of a battery that's exhausted it's life. It's good to check another charger or cable as they are less expensive than a battery swap. Especially if you can't get diagnostics run on the iPad to determine the age of the battery. Odds are it's an old battery on an iPad 3 in 2017, but good thinking for other causes.